# Playing music that is linked and not loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably an odd question, but for fun i recreated the Spotify layout to their app in codepen, now I want to add some functionality, is there a way I can get music to play using JS or jQuery?

My first thought was to embed the video and hide it behind the play button, but that doesn't quite work for me.

Is there a way I can set a `var` where I set it `=` to a url, then use an `onclick` or `toggle` command to play the url?

The only way I could think about going this would be:

```
var expirePrettyLow = 'url:www.fake.com'

$('#play').toggle(
    function(){
//play youtube link?

);
```

I hope this makes sense, is there an api I can call to just get the mp3s? I don't want to upload them since it's just linking, not trying to make a product out of this, just to add to portfolio.

For reference here is my **[codepen link](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/EaqvoK)**.

Thanks for whatever advice/direction you can give me!

EDIT: To clarify, by 'linked' and not 'loaded'
I would like to accomplish this by linking to a url (ie: `href=""`) as opposed to saving it in my directory and loading it through a filepath (ie: `music/tracks/expire-prettylow.mp3`)

Comment: HTML5 has an audio tag: you can do <audio id="demo" src="audio.mp3"></audio> and control is: document.getElementById('demo').play();

Comment: "*is there an api I can call to just get the mp3s?*" Are you asking about Spotify APIs? If so, the `[spotify]` tag is appropriate.

Comment: So say I wanted to use this **[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpU3_i0FGMw)**, I would need to set the audio id onto my play button so `<div class="play"><audio id="pretty-low" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpU3_i0FGMw"></audio></div>` ?

Then use `document.getElementById('pretty-low').onClick.play();` to make it so it plays on click?

Comment: @apsillers I've seen the spotify api, but never saw it used to play music, just to pull lists from spotify, a buddy of mine used to to pull all the bands for certain search terms, but his wasn't able to play either.

Comment: If you're using YouTube videos (as you suggest in your comment, but don't say for sure anywhere), you may be interested in the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: @apsillers, oops, yes I was planning to use youtube videos as I am unsure of anywhere else I would be able to find the tracks. However I don't want to see the video, I just would like it to play the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User a blank audio tag and set the play button's onClick to "var newSrc = newSource.com/song.mp3; playTrack()", and have the playTrack() function load and play the song. Here's an example of a code that changes the source of the audio element then plays the new source.

```
<script>
function playTrack(){
    var music = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    music.src = newSrc;
    music.load();
    music.play();
}
</script>
<audio id="myAudio" src="">
Audio tag not supported
</audio>
Click a song to play it:
<ul>
    <li onClick="newSrc = 'http://fidelak.free.fr/reprises/The%20Doors%20-%20People%20are%20Strange.mp3'; playTrack()">People are Strange</li>
    <li onClick="newSrc = 'http://mp3light.net/assets/songs/14000-14999/14781-december-1963-oh-what-a-night-four-seasons--1411568407.mp3'; playTrack()">Oh What a Night</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just tested this, EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you very much for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Set the src with JavScript, music.load(), then music.play()

Comment: Right but doesnt really answer the question.